# XSLT: saving the loop content to variable and print it out

Tags: xml, xslt, iteration

I am new to the xsl and never used it before. I hope to get some help. I want to save the loop content to a variable `loop_content` and print it like `1, 2, 3`. Nothing is being printed out with my xsl and xml files. The output is an empty file.

I am using the following xsl file

**.xsl file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
                version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="loop_content">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$loop_content"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**xml document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<doc>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
    <c>3</c>
</doc>
```

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced using your code: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVTWaz5

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thanks for your replay. I checked it again and the poblem has with the eclipse run configuration. I cleaned some transformation pipeline in Eclipse and I can see the expected result `1, 2, 3`